# Format String for SQL Entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

The user enters the date as `MM/DD/YYYY` in a string and it needs to be formatted in C#/ASP.NET for insertion into a SQL Server 2008 R2 record. I understand I should convert it to a datetime and parameterize it into the query, but can't find an example of this.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DateTime.Parse and in your query add the re turned DateTime as parameter.

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(theString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into xxx (theDateField) values(@param1)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", date);

//execute your query and do what even you want.
```

Comment: That parameter method (`AddParameterWithName`) is invalid in C#

Comment: Woah, sorry, I was really sleepy when wrote that, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that question is answered but this might be also helpful

```
DateTime regDate = DateTime.MinValue;

    if (txtDate.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        string[] ddmmyyyy = txtDate.Text.Trim().Split(new char[] { '-', '/' });
        regDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ddmmyyyy[1] + "/" + ddmmyyyy[0] + "/" + ddmmyyyy[2]);
    }
```

Now your date is ready you can insert in database using whatever method you like.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegDate", regDate);
```

or

```
SqlParameter paramRegDate = new SqlParameter("@RegDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
selCmd.Parameters.Add(paramRegDate);
```